# How to add placeholder text in a dropdown list on Sitecore Forms?

Tags: sitecore-forms

What we wanted to do was to have placeholder text in our DDLs that:

- will trigger data validation if not changed from its default value
- is non-selectable after a choice has been made

Issues:

- Sitecore does not allow you to add an option to a DDL with a blank value.

How can we do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Decide on a convention like 'placeholder' or 'null' as the Value of the default option you want to use

[image: Like this...]

- Go into your webroot to: **...\Views\FormBuilder\FieldTemplates\DropdownList.cshtml** and modify like this

  ```
   @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
   {
       if (item.Value.ToLowerInvariant() == "placeholder"){
           <option value="" selected="@item.Selected" disabled hidden>@item.Text</option>
       }else{
           <option value="@item.Value" selected="@item.Selected">@item.Text</option>
       }
   }
  ```

Note:

- set the attributes 'disabled' and 'hidden' (this will make it non-selectable after a choice is made)
- set 'value' to "" (value="" will trigger the validation when the submit button is pressed)

[image: are of interest err msg]
[image: DDL area of interest]
[image: ddl area of interest placeholder gone]